# Disciplined and peer pressure badges

Tags: support, badges, self-delete

The Peer Pressure badge is awarded if you delete your own post with a score of -3 or less. The Disciplined badge is awarded if you delete your own post with a score of 3 or more.

My question is, how do you delete your own post? I can vote for the deletion of my own questions, but I can't delete them outright as Stack Overflow doesn't seem to let you do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post a bad answer and brag about it. That should do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My question is... how do you delete your own post? I can vote my own questions for deletion but I can't delete them outright as stackoverflow doesn't seem to let you do that.

You can delete any answer at any time, without needing votes.  It is by design that a question cannot be deleted at a whim by the person who posted it (if it has at least one answer with a score of +1).

So while you could, in theory, get the badge for deleting an answer-less question with a score of +/-3, the badge is generally geared towards answers.